# RegEx to remove http://www. if it exists in PHP and JS

Tags: php, javascript, regex

Could someone please help me with a regular expression (I need it in php and in js) to remove http:// and www. from the beginning of a url string and remove the trailing / if its there.

For Example

- `http://www.google.com/` would be `google.com`
- `https://yahoo.com?page=1`
  would be `yahoo.com?page=1`
- `fancysite.com/articles/2012/` would be
  `fancysite.com/articles/2012`

Heres the code Im using for the JS side:

```
row.page_href.replace(/^(https?|ftp):\/\//, '')
```

And heres the code Im using for the php side:

```
$urlString = rtrim($urlString, '/');
$urlString = preg_replace('~^(?:https?://)?(?:www[.])?~i', '', $urlString);
```

As you can see the JS regex only removes http:// currently and the php requires two steps to do everything.

Comment: Why don't you add the `www` to the JS regex? Or why don't you use the the same in both cases? I don't think PHP *requires* you trim a possible `/` from the end of the string... that's just how you choose to do it.

Comment: May i ask why? is this for just anchor text?

Comment: The *right* regular expression will work in both JS and PHP.

Comment: Its a requirement for my project... Why are you questioning why I need something? And no this isn't for anchor text at all.

Comment: But... what's the problem with `^(?:https?://)?(?:www[.])?`? Looks fine to me, just use it in JS and PHP.

Comment: @RachelD: I'm not asking to offend, merely curious. Also, dropping the trailing `/` (in some instances) can invalidate a url.

Comment: Felix, It wasn't working when I tried it in the JS (Im new at using regex's so I thought my format was off).

Comment: Sorry I don't mean to be snippy I just get a lot of non answers on here telling me that I shouldn't be doing whatever I'm trying to do, then I get suggestions for things that I'm not trying to do. I'm trying to create a neatened URL that will be the anchor text for the full link to display as results for something. As per my boss I need them trimmed a certian way.

Comment: `str = str.replace(/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www[.])?/, '')` would be how you do it in JS. More about regex in JS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions.

Answer (score 4):

```
function cleanUrl($url)
{
  if (($d= parse_url($url)) !== false) // valid url
  {
    return sprintf('%s%s%s',
      ltrim($d['host'], 'www.'),
      rtrim($d['path']. '/'),
      !empty($d['query']) ? '?'.$d['query'] : '');
  }
  return $url;
}
```

I would take advantage of [parse_url](http://www.php.net/parse_url) (validate the url along with 'clean' it)

Comment: Uh-duh, why didn't I think of that. I always forget about that function for soem reason. Use this OP.

Comment: I was going with the regex because I assumed it was faster than parsing and trimming the URL. Am I mistaken in my assumption?

Comment: @RachelD: Regex requires more overhead than the [php's plain string parser](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/url.c#L97-L370). For this reason, I consider regex more overhead than is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

`#(https?(://))?(www.?)?(.*)#i`

Worked just fine for me. You could change the last `(.*)` to match the RFC standards of a URL.

Outputs:

```
david@david-desktop ~ $ php -a
Interactive shell

php > $str = preg_replace('#(https?(://))?(www.?)?(.*)#i', '$4', 'https://www.google.ca');
php > echo $str . PHP_EOL;
google.ca
php > $str = preg_replace('#(https?(://))?(www.?)?(.*)#i', '$4', 'https://google.ca');
php > echo $str . PHP_EOL;
google.ca
php > $str = preg_replace('#(https?(://))?(www.?)?(.*)#i', '$4', 'http://google.ca');
php > echo $str . PHP_EOL;
google.ca
php >
```

Comment: Thank you I had something very similar to this but it wasn't doing what I wanted so I thought I was on the wrong trail. I will play with this more.